# Authoritatively deleting cross questions

Tags: support, comments

In specific reference to [this question.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139314/)

A comment (by me) under [Poutnik's post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/139316/) was deleted which was actually a counter question to the answer proposed by the method.

My questions:

1. Who have the authority to delete comments except moderators?[now answered]
2. Justify the deletion.

Ofcourse comments are temporary but deletion of everything, even the counter-comments to an answer, that's what I have not seen around in any other community yet.

The comment I made looked something like :

" Using the fast reactions, the output of the answer is different from the output mentioned in this adopted method. where is the supposedely 'wrong here'"

Comment: If a comment is flagged three times, it gets automatically deleted. Comments that contain  certain trigger words can get deleted by a single flag. Other than that, only moderators can delete comments. The tone of your meta post is definitely uncalled for, as is the "MODZ DEL EVRYTHING" accusation.

Comment: @M.A.R. the modz del everythng is an accusation made by you. The comment flagged three times on an inactive post...fishy...ENquiry: can you see deleted comments? if so is there any log as such

Comment: Also, for uninitiated people who cannot see deleted comments...as mentioned in the question, it did not contain any trigger words, just counter question. Perhaps a moderator who can see the comment quote it here.

Comment: Only moderators can see (and I think undelete) deleted comments. There's no log as far as I know, and unless abusive comments form a pattern, there are no penalties for having your comment deleted. Why is the comment on an 'inactive' post really that important, then? If you mean to challenge the content of the answer, simply do so.

Comment: @M.A.R. the content of the answer was challenged using the comment feature (perhaps not the right way...then what?). I read about the undeletion on meta.se, but didn't find about logs. I am not concerned about the penalties, rather it concerns being "silencio"ed. 3flags on an "inactive" post is not a mere coincidence

Comment: Unless you know the commenter, it could be a possibility that they deleted the comment themselves, or that the moderator saw the thread explode and simply purged the whole thing themselves. These are not details I would be privy to, but I'm not sure a mod is under any obligation to reveal such information when you accuse them of being authoritarian, the authority which was granted to them by the community in an electoral process.

Comment: @M.A.R. I know the commentor...It is ME!. The authority of deleting comments is with the moderators, staff and "community flags" which is a new knowledge (and that's why the title of question). I do not know what you want to say by the last two lines...granting authority and accepting authority? Perhaps an elected "government" is definitely accountable for their actions.

Comment: Second time mentioning: The comment was posted yesterday after the thread was inactive for 6 days.

Comment: Then you can perhaps quote the comment as best as you remember it, and mention the fact that you're the author in the post, which would be much more helpful than all else that is in this meta post. These are crucial pieces of information and I feel leaving them out can be disingenuous. Here are a few posts about deleting comments on main meta which I feel are relevant: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233698/), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302733/moderator-political-censorship), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237982/280934)

Comment: How is that comment still valid? Could you delete something that is just cluttering the answer? It has been inactive for three days again...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments in question were routine clarifications on the post. The original author had offered appropriate explanations. The comments were flagged as "no longer necessary", and since they were no longer necessary, they were subsequently deleted by a moderator. That was not me, but I fully agree with the action taken.

Comment: Can you check whether the clarification to my comment was offered. Because it was just yesterday and I did not receive any notification

Comment: I undeleted the comments.

Comment: Thanks, it was deleted fast.